# Why does window.requestAnimationFrame not keeping the last transition?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, requestanimationframe

i'm trying to build my own simple fullpage.js or something similar, just so I can learn more about how to use `requestAnimationFrame` function, however I am stuck into this problem of transform3d value resetting, which behaves like this

[image]

You can see in the gif that every time I switch slides, the animation starts always at the first slide

Here is the implementation of the slider
html

```html
<div class="scroller">
   <div class="scroller-content">
      <section class="scroller-section s1">SLIDE 1</section>
      <section class="scroller-section s2">SLIDE 2</section>
      <section class="scroller-section s3">SLIDE 3</section>
      <section class="scroller-section s4">SLIDE 4</section>
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```css
.scroller {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scroller-section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 25rem;
}

.scroller-section.s1 {
  background-color: #535bf2;
}
.scroller-section.s2 {
  background-color: #242424;
}

.scroller-section.s3 {
  background-color: #213547;
}

.scroller-section.s4 {
  background-color: #747bff;
}
```

```js
const scrollerContent = document.querySelector(".scroller-content")

const offsets = [0, -100, -200, -300]

let index = 0

window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {

  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    index = shift(index + 1) // go next
    const offset = offsets[index]

    createAnimationFrames((delta) => {
      scrollerContent.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${delta * offset}vh,0)`
    }, 1000)
 
  } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {

    index = shift(index - 1) // go prev
    const offset = offsets[index]

    createAnimationFrames((delta) => {
      scrollerContent.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${delta * offset}vh,0)`
    }, 1000)
      
  }
})
```

Here is the implementation of `createAnimationFrames`

```js
const createAnimationFrames = (callback: (delta: number) => void, duration: number) => {
  let start = new Date();
  let raf = requestAnimationFrame;

  const animate = () => {
    let now = new Date();

    const delta = Math.min((now.getTime() - start.getTime()) / duration, 1);

    callback(delta);

    if (delta < 1) {
      raf(animate);
    }
  };

  raf(animate);
};
```

Basically it runs the callback every frame request and the callback takes `delta` as a reference for the progress of the animation.

The thing is that it works normally by just having a simple reassign to the `transform` attribute and not using the `requestAnimationFrame`. Any solutions for this?

Comment: Can you attach a working snippet with CSS and HTML, so we can provide you a successful answer. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot, done editing!